# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children})

Tags: reactjs

I have read an interesting article that suggests to use a custom usechildProps hook to directly write dynamic elements in the parent rather than sending props. The article is here: https://medium.com/the-guild/the-coolest-most-underrated-design-pattern-in-react-cd6210956203

Basically, instead of writing:

```js
<Modal
  showCloseButton
  showDismissButton
  showActionButton
  title="Modal title"
  contents="Modal body text goes here."
  dismissButtonText="Close"
  actionButtonText="Save changes"
  handleDismiss={close}
  handleAction={save}
/>
```

One could write:

```js
<Modal>
  <title>Modal title</title>
  <contents>Modal body text goes here.</contents>
  <dismissButton onClick={close}>Close</dismissButton>
  <actionButton onClick={save}>Save changes</actionButton>
</Modal>
```

So, I've tried to reproduce the example given by the author, but it doesn't work. React claims that:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

The useChildProp hooks is:

```js
import { useMemo } from "react";

const useChildProps = (children, whitelist) => {
  return useMemo(() =>
    [].concat(children).reduce(
      (childProps, child) => {
        if (whitelist && !whitelist.includes(child.type)) {
          throw Error(`element <${child.type}> is not supported`);
        }
        childProps[child.type] = child.props;
        return childProps;
      },
      [children]
    )
  );
};

export default useChildProps;
```

The component:

```js
import useChildProps from "./useChildProps";

const ModalFromTheFuture = ({ children }) => {
  const childProps = useChildProps(children, [
    "title",
    "contents",
    "actionButton",
    "cancelButton"
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <header>{childProps.title && <h1> {childProps.title}</h1>}</header>
      <section>
        <p>{childProps.contents && childProps.contents}</p>
      </section>
      <footer>
        {childProps.actionButton && <button {...childProps.actionButton} />}
        {childProps.dismissButton && <button {...childProps.cancelButton} />}
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ModalFromTheFuture;
```

How to fix this? This pattern seems very interesting.

I have read related threads. I know this issue is normally caused by not destructuring props.children. But I've done it here. Hence my question.

ps: here is also a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tereshkova-8i0wm?file=/src/ComponentPattern.js:0-646

Comment: where are you using `useChildProps`?

Comment: The question has been updated, with a sandbox. The issue seems to come from the useChildProp hook at the line childProps[child.type] = child.props;. If I replace child.props by a string, it works.

Comment: `childProps.title` is an object.

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox, that made it a lot easier to debug.

Comment: This is a weird design pattern.  I don’t get why you wouldn’t just use the children prop the “normal” way and make a Modal element that accepts JSX element children instead of using these psuedo-elements like dismissButton that don’t really exist.  There is huge potential for uncaught errors from wrong elements, and eslint will have no idea what elements are allowed.

Comment: Yes, it's very weird, but I was interested in understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you are trying to use an object as a react component (`childProp.title`, and `childProp.content`). It seems you want to use their children as "content".

```js
import { useMemo } from "react";

const useChildProps = (children, whitelist) => {
  return useMemo(() =>
    [].concat(children).reduce(
      (childProps, child) => {
        if (whitelist && !whitelist.includes(child.type)) {
          throw Error(`element <${child.type}> is not supported`);
        }
        childProps[child.type] = child.props;
        return childProps;
      },
      {})  // better make this an object, not an array that you were monkey-patching properties into
  );
};

export default useChildProps;
```

```js
import useChildProps from "./useChildProps";

const ModalFromTheFuture = ({ children }) => {
  const childProps = useChildProps(children, [
    "title",
    "contents",
    "actionButton",
    "cancelButton"
  ]);
  console.log(childProps);
  delete childProps.actionButton.children;
  delete childProps.cancelButton.children;

  return (
    <div>
      <header>{childProps.title && <h1> {childProps.title.children}</h1>}</header>

      <section>
        <p>{childProps.contents && childProps.contents.children}</p>
      </section>

      <footer>
        {childProps.actionButton && <button {...childProps.actionButton} />}
        {childProps.dismissButton && <button {...childProps.cancelButton} />}
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};
```